# Adding a 2x Picture Widget on home screen

Tags: app-widgets, images

I have a Samsung Galaxy S4.

I have a picture that I would like to have as a 2x2 widget. I don't want to set it as  background; I want it like the Weather widget.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a 2x2 Picture widget. Drag it to your home screen.

[image]

Here's what it would look like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with my **free** app [Showr](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.shadowburst.showr&referrer=ase48211). With Showr, you can choose a picture from another app (such as the Gallery or Dropbox), you can take it directly with any camera app, or you can have it download from the Internet and update by your schedule.

Showr lets you resize the widget to any size. You can also set what happens when you click on the photo widget: you might want to view the photo in the Gallery, or start some other app, or launch a website. And because I'm active on this site, you know it's going to be easy to get help if you need it.

[image: Get Showr on Google Play]

Comment: This link is now dead